# A notion of "number of distinct variables"

Tags: probability, gaussian

Suppose $X = (X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$ is a multivariate Gaussian vector. I am interested in creating a notion of $N =$ how many "distinct" Gaussian random variables there are.

Here are some examples of what I am looking for.

Example 1: If all are i.i.d. standard normal, then $N=4.$

Example 2: If $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are i.i.d. standard normal and $X_4=X_3,$ then $N=3.$ However, if $X_4 = X_3 + \epsilon Y$ where $Y$ is independent standard normal and $\epsilon <<1$, then $N = 3 + f(\epsilon)$ where $f(\epsilon)\to 0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.

Desired properties:

a) For $n$ variables, we have $N\leq n.$

b) If a new set of jointly Gaussian variables is appended to a given vector, then $N$ can only increase.

It seems that $N$ should be some simple property of the correlation matrix of the variables. In particular, it seems like it should be some property of the eigenvalues of the correlation matrix.

But I am not able to pin down exactly what it is. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: It looks like this might work. First, normalize all variables to have a variance of 1. Then, $N = \mathrm{Var}(X_1) + \mathrm{Var}(X_2|X_1) + \mathrm{Var}(X_3|X_1,X_2) + \ldots $. This would work but only if it can be shown that $N$ is invariant to permutation of the elements of the Gaussian vector.

Further EDIT: Some numerical calculations seem to show the proposed formula is invariant to permutation. Just working to prove it now.

Comment: What should happen in the case that $X_4 = X_2^2 + X_3^2$ where $X_2, X_3$ are standard normal.

Comment: Basically more concretely, given an arbitrary function $F(X_3)$ how do you compute your $f(\epsilon)$? This operator needs to be defined. (For the record, I think this question hints at something very interesting despite being ill defined)

Comment: If you are restricting yourself to only looking at Gaussian random variables, maybe consider the rank of the covariance matrix. It satisfies a) and b).

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: We cannot have $X_4 = X^2+X_3^2$ due to the restriction that $X$ is a multivariate normal vector. Only the covariance matrix of $X$ is important. And futher, only the correlation matrix need be relevant because I would like it to be scale invariant. Similarly, arbitrary function $F$ is ruled out because of multivariate normality of the vector.

Comment: i see, great! that restricts a lot of things that could've gone wrong

Comment: @maxbaroi: Rank of covariance matrix is somewhat inadequate for me. For example, consider two variables with correlation $\rho$. The rank is 2 for $\rho\neq 0$ and 1 when $\rho=0.$ I am looking at something like $\frac{2}{1+\rho^2}$ which moves smoothly between 2 and 1 for $\rho$ going from 0 to 1. I arrived at this by $\frac{k^2}{\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i^2}$ for a $k\times k$ covariance matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$. It works in the 2$\times$2 case but does not work more generally.

Comment: @maxbaroi: Note that $\sum_i \lambda_i^2$ lies in $[k,k^2]$ by Cauchy-Schwartz and the fact that the trace is $k$.